# Does pure electric dipole have higher order moments?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Of course for the standard configuration(i.e. two opposite charges separated by some distance), there exist higher order multipole moments. However for an ideal dipole(those dipoles associated with point mass, which means the separation is zero), are there any higher order moments?

Comment: No. The contributings of a pure dipole are purely dipole.

Comment: A *pure* dipole is *defined* by the condition that its multipole expansion has only a dipole term, so the the answer is no by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Even a single point-like monopole displaced from the origin will have higher multipoles if we expand it's field with respect to the origin, see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17063/389318)! The same is valid for the dipole. However, a [point-like dipole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/336497/389318) at the origin has a trivial expansion with respect to the same origin. Therefore, in order to have an expansion that is as simple as possible (namely, where the first terms are possibly zero), you should consider to expand your distribution around its [center of charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/794331/389318).