# Electric dipole moment and charge density

Tags: electrostatics, charge, dipole, dipole-moment, multipole-expansion

I came across the following expression about the electric dipole moment:

$\vec p=\int_V \rho(\vec {r}')\vec r'$

But I don't understand it. What is $\vec r'$ supposed to represent and the density? Are we observing some region with a charge distribution and we take a small infinitesimal volume $dV$ and also the charge density there?

The expression I know for the dipole moment is: $\vec p= q\vec a$. Here $q$ is the charge value, and $\vec a$ a vector from the negative charge to the positive.

How does the above formula resembles to the last one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multipole Expansion: Electrostatics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280386/)

Comment: That's what I am reading but that does explain as to why. It just presents it as a fact.

Comment: Look up the posts (or book chapters) on *multipole expansion*.